# Move an object in a direction

Tags: game-maker

I have to work in Game Maker for this project and I want to move a object towards another object. This is what I have got so far. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? The enemy is now spinning around the player.

```
draw_sprite(sprite_index,image_index,x,y);
moveSpeed = 1;
angle = arctan2(enemy_obj.x - player_obj.x, enemy_obj.y - player_obj.y);
enemy_obj.x += cos(angle) * moveSpeed;
enemy_obj.y -= sin(angle) * moveSpeed;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use builtin GM-functions (this code must be placed in the `end step` event of the enemy object):

```
angle = point_direction(x, y, player_obj.x, player_obj.y);
x += lengthdir_x(moveSpeed, angle);
y += lengthdir_y(moveSpeed, angle);
```

or:

```
direction = point_direction(x, y, player_obj.x, player_obj.y);
if point_distance(x, y, player_obj.x, player_obj.y) > 10 // min distance
{
    speed = moveSpeed;
}
```

Or you can use motion planning functions, like `mp_potential_step` or `mp_grid_...` for [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm).

P.S. When you use code like this

```
angle = arctan2(enemy_obj.x - player_obj.x, enemy_obj.y - player_obj.y);
```

you must understand that if are several instances of `enemy_obj` then will be taken only very first of them (with the smallest id)

Comment: Why does this code have to go in the end_step event instead of just the step event?

Comment: Because all instances changes positions after the `step` event and before the `end step` event. For example, if your object `obj_player` have speed 4 and position x=0 then `x = obj_player.x` for the `step` event will be 0, but for the `step end` event will be 4. So if I do `direction = point_direction(x, y, player_obj.x, player_obj.y)` in the `step` event it will use old `player_obj` position and you will see a some delay.